# Wrong week_of_month and day_of_month returned

Tags: android, gregorian-calendar

Here's my code:

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
c.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, selectedWeek);
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, selectedYear);

Log.v(FILE_NAME,"C content: " + c.toString());

int firstDayOfWeek = c.getFirstDayOfWeek();
String[] days = new String[firstDayOfWeek + 7];

for (int i = firstDayOfWeek; i < firstDayOfWeek + 7; i++) {
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, i);
    days[i] = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM").format(c.getTime());             
}

Log.v(FILE_NAME, "Start " + days[firstDayOfWeek] + " to " + days[firstDayOfWeek + 6]);
```

I set selectedWeek to 51, selectedYear to 2016. So my expectation was, since I already gave the week and year, in my last Log.v, I should be getting the list of dates in the given week (51), which is 19 Dec to 25 Dec. Instead I'll always get the dates in the current week (for example, currently I will always get 12 Dec to 18 Dec)

Displaying the contents of c gives me

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=Asia/Kuala_Lumpur,firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2016,MONTH=11,WEEK_OF_YEAR=52,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=18,DAY_OF_YEAR=353,DAY_OF_WEEK=1,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=0,HOUR=1,HOUR_OF_DAY=1,MINUTE=24,SECOND=46,MILLISECOND=30,ZONE_OFFSET=28800000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

It seems WEEK_OF_MONTH returns the CURRENT WEEK_OF_MONTH, not of the given selectedWeek and selectedYear. Same goes to DAY_OF_MONTH. My assumption was the DAY_OF_MONTH should at least return the starting date of the given selectedWeek?

Did I understand wrongly? If I did, what should I do so that days[firstDayOfWeek] returns the first day in the given the week and year?

Comment: Try initializing calender with current date and then modify it, u might not providing all the values to make a calendar like time etc. 
`Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();`

Comment: @AbrahamGharyali I don't get what you meant by I might not provide all the values to make calendar like time. I've already provided the week and year, and that's the only value that I have. Btw I did `Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();` but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Try also `c.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4);` to achieve an ISO-8601-week-date-configuration. It is not sufficient to only define the first day-of-week. And since Android-API-level 24, there is also a method [setWeekDate](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#setWeekDate) which should be preferred (said within the scope of this not so pretty API - there are better time libraries around).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out the problem. The thing is when you set `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK` , the calendar resets itself and just change the day of week to what you are setting it. 
So to make your code work, you have to set `Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR` inside the for loop.

```
for (int i = firstDayOfWeek; i < firstDayOfWeek + 7; i++) {
            c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, i);
            c.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, selectedWeek);
            days[i] = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM").format(c.getTime());
        }
```

Comment: I decided to use JodaTime library instead which is much much better than this default library to get what I need. Nevertheless, I tried your solution and it works. Thanks